# How to find and remove duplicates of paired data that in an array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, duplicates

Document in my collection looks like one below. How to count the duplicates amount when two pair of strings (**user** and **a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1**) is the same as in example? And how to remove one of these pair?

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5ea3138daee55c0001eac29f"),
"linkRole" : [
        {
            "role" : "admin",
            "Organization" : "a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1"
        },
        {
            "role" : "superadmin",
            "Organization" : "a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1"
        },
        {
            "role" : "user",
            "Organization" : "a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1"
        },
        {
            "role" : "user",
            "Organization" : "a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1"
        },
        {
            "role" : "admin",
            "Organization" : "dd79f23d-2382-4eb7-a2f3-634890eba0bb"
        },
        {
            "role" : "superadmin",
            "Organization" : "dd79f23d-2382-4eb7-a2f3-634890eba0bb"
        }]
```

Same document:

```
linkRole[0].role:admin
linkRoles[0].Organization:a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1
linkRole[1].role:superadmin
linkRoles[1].Organization:a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1
linkRole[2].role:user
linkRoles[2].Organization:a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1
linkRole[3].role:user
linkRoles[3].Organization:a32cc286-256b-40e5-fc5d-5ecbdc341ab1
linkRole[4].role:admin
linkRoles[4].Organization:dd79f23d-2382-4eb7-a2f3-634890eba0bb
linkRole[5].role:superadmin
linkRoles[5].Organization:dd79f23d-2382-4eb7-a2f3-634890eba0bb
```

I use this code to get duplicates. And have documents with 2..3..10 of them. Now i need to remove all of them, but save 1 unique string.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$linkRole"},
    {$group: {"_id": {org: "$linkRole.Organization", role: "$linkRole.role"},
    count: {"$sum": 1}}},
         {$match: { "count": { "$gte": 2 }}})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this aggregation can help you

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$linkRole"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Organization": "$linkRole.Organization",
        "role": "$linkRole.role"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "role": "$_id.role",
      "Organization": "$_id.Organization"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qWVlW-E0spB)

Comment: @AntonS. Glad to hear it. Can you please upvote and accept my answer if it's been useful for you, please?

Comment: Upvoted already, but i have <15 rep to view this. And now need to remove all duplicates in my case to solve the problem :)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I understood what you meant. Aggregation I gave was already removing duplicates? What's missing in it? Do you want count field too?

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline = [
  {$unwind: "$linkRole"},
  {$group: {
    _id: {
      d_id: "$_id",
      role: "$linkRole.role",
      Organization: "$linkRole.Organization"
    },
    count: {$sum: 1}
  }},
  {$match:{count: {$gt: 1}}}
]
db.users.aggregate(pipeline).forEach(a => {
  user = db.users.findOne({_id: a._id.d_id});
  for (let i = 1; i < a.count; i++) {
    user.linkRole.splice(
      user.linkRole.findIndex(lr => lr.role === a._id.role && lr.Organization === a._id.Organization),
      1
    )
  }
  db.users.save(user)
})
```

Thank you, @AlexoLive from habr.